CSS transition width glitch when hovering between HTML elements
I have a row of items that transition in width using cubic-bezier. When hovering over the white gaps between the items the width glitches, getting larger and smaller very quickly. How do I fix? -


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  transition: width 0.5s cubic-bezier(.87, -1.38, .03, 1.54);
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2024/07/03/08/05/hot-air-balloon-8869138_1280.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item:hover {
  width: 500px;
}
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>



codepen

That is because cubic-bezier will make it bigger and then smaller - Meaning that when you go from hover to the whitespace, then the cubic-bezier will make the item bigger and hit your cursor, making you hover again. If you use linear then it works fine. - Or that is my guess

You can fill the gap between .item with a pseudo-elements:


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  --gap: 20px;
  display: flex;
  gap: var(--gap);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.item {
  filter: grayscale(1);
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  transition: width 0.7s cubic-bezier(.87, -0.2, .05, 1.54), filter .3s linear;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2024/07/03/08/05/hot-air-balloon-8869138_1280.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  &:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0 calc(-1 * var(--gap));
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}

.item:hover {
  width: 500px;
  filter: grayscale(0);
  &:before {
    pointer-events: auto;
  }
}
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>




Like others already mentioned in the comments below your question, this is because cubic-bezier makes it bigger than smaller.
You can use transition-delay property to partially mitigate that problem.
It will not entirely fix it, but gives the user enough time to move with his mouse over the next item.
However, if you are too slow or keep your mouse between the items on purpose, it will still "glitch".
Example with 250ms delay, maybe you have to play around with the delay:


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  transition: width 0.5s cubic-bezier(.87, -1.38, .03, 1.54);
  transition-delay: 250ms;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2024/07/03/08/05/hot-air-balloon-8869138_1280.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item:hover {
  width: 500px;
}
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>



